How to configure the Original language of an SAP workflow?
I am trying to edit a standard workflow but it is not editable. Whenever I click on the edit button it is giving a message that "Object maintenance in this system only possible in original language". Usually the message specifies the original language in this message, but in this one it is not specified. I tried to log in German and Russian as well but could not make it editable.
I would appreciate any help and suggestion.
I tried to look for a table that contains the original language of standard programs but could not find any. Also, in Eclipse in righ click -> show in -> properties, the original language field is empty for the workflow that I want to edit. For others it does contain value.

You should not change the standard workflows. You should copy, maintain the copy, and trigger the copy instead of the standard. During any patch or upgrade, the standard workflows may be changed or overridden without warning, and you would lose your changes. For information, the original/master language is in the Object Directory Entry (SM30 > TADIR > R3TR PFWS <workflow number>).

SM30 > TADIR > R3TR PDWS 

Thanks @SandraRossi. The Masterlang field is empty. Can I fill it out manually?

Dear @SandraRossi, Thanks for your response. I found it very useful. I am not able to change the original language. It is disabled for change.

I never changed standard workflows, nor changed the original language of workflows. Instead, you should copy, etc.

The original language field is empty. Can workflows come with no original language?

You cannot change the original language of a workflow.
The text "Object maintenance in this system only possible in original language &" (message number 040 of message class ET) where & is replaced with the original language. If it's not shown, it means that the original language is empty, it's abnormal but it may happen if there was a bug at the time of the creation, or the field was filled after this workflow was created, or any other reason.
For information, the original language can be seen in the Object Directory Entry (Transaction code SM30 > Table TADIR > Object key R3TR PDWS ) but it cannot be changed. The original language is stored in the column MASTERLANG of the table TADIR. If you change it by any means, there's no guarantee about the impact of this unpermitted change.
Anyway, I guess you should not change the standard workflows. Instead, do copy ("Save as"), maintain the copy, and trigger the copy instead of the standard. During any patch or upgrade, the standard workflows may possibly be changed or overridden without warning, and you might possibly lose your changes. By copying the workflow, you'd be able to see what has been changed in the standard and decide if you reapply the standard modifications.

What if the MASTERLANG field is empty? In my case, this field is empty. Then whatever is the language of logon, the message is "Object maintenance in this system only possible in original language "

All is in my answer. "You cannot change the original language of a workflow." And "If you change it by any means, there's no guarantee about the impact of this unpermitted change." The solution explained here is to NOT change the workflow but copy it, no need to repeat the question again, just wait for other answers if you wish.
